# Remove specific character from entire dataframe but keep same data types?

Tags: r

Lets simulate some data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
set.seed(1)

a<-round(rnorm(20,5,5))
b<-stri_rand_strings(20, 5, pattern = "[A-Z,]")
ab<-cbind.data.frame(a,b)
```

When we check for data type of the first column, it is coded as "double"

```
typeof(ab[,1])
```

I want to get rid of all commas that are potentially present in the dataframe, so I used this code:

```
ab1<-ab %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., ",", "")))

typeof(ab1[,1])
```

This however, also converts data type of column 1 into a character, which has unfortunate consequences on further data parsing. Is there a way to target a whole data frame and remove a certain character from it, but keep the same data type as in the original data frame? I really don't want to write names of 50 columns and convert them back to numeric.

Edit: Just in case it wasn't clear, I am hoping for a solution that targets the whole data frame, not specific columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about removing commas from just character columns?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
set.seed(1)

a<-round(rnorm(20,5,5))
b<-stri_rand_strings(20, 5, pattern = "[A-Z,]")
ab<-cbind.data.frame(a,b)

ab1 <- ab %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ stringr::str_remove_all(.x, ",")))
glimpse(ab1)
#> Rows: 20
#> Columns: 2
#> $ a <dbl> 2, 6, 1, 13, 7, 1, 7, 9, 8, 3, 13, 7, 2, -6, 11, 5, 5, 10, 9, 8
#> $ b <chr> "VQUNN", "ULSR", "LWKFA", "BHNQJ", "XGLHQ", "FLTBW", "IVIIL", "XWJTY…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

By the way, using `funs()` should generate a deprecated warning in recent tidyverse versions and `mutate_all()` is also superseded by `mutate(across())`